# How to iterate through nested objects in a generic way

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to fetch the value of the nested objects without using it's key. Like for example if I have a object like

`var a = {"key" : "100"}`

I don't want to use `a.key`, to get the result, though i have nested objects, it is becoming difficult for me to fetch the value this is what I have tried:

```
var Obj = [{"ghi":{"content":"abc"}},{"def":{"imgURL":"test.png"}},{"abc":{"key":"001"}},{"ghi":{"content":"abc"}},{"def":{"imgURL":"test.png"}},{"abc":{"key":"001"}}]

for(var key in Obj){
 abc = Obj[key]
 for(var j in abc){
  def = abc[key]
 }
}
```

So i need the values of all the objects, without using the key directly.

Comment: and which value like you to get?

Comment: @Nina Scholz, Under ghi, there is content i need it's value and similar like this for all the objects in my array

Comment: but you have more than one `ghi` properties?

Comment: That list of objects does not look like it has any kind of structure. Differently named keys means you'll have to iterate through them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```js
function getValues(array, key) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        a[key] && result.push(a[key]);
    });
    return result;
}

var array = [{ "ghi": { "content": "abc" } }, { "def": { "imgURL": "test.png" } }, { "abc": { "key": "001" } }, { "ghi": { "content": "abc" } }, { "def": { "imgURL": "test.png" } }, { "abc": { "key": "001" } }];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getValues(array, 'ghi'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```